# Keeping track and handling multiple Ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Imagine a table with 4 accordion tabs hidden on each row. When a row is clicked/expanded 4 Ajax calls are fired to load data into the accordion tabs.

Tab 1 and 2 loads very quickly but 3 and 4 takes a lot longer time. When another row is expanded, the same 4 ajax calls are fired. If I minimize the other row I want to abort the ongoing ajax calls for that specific row, but still load in the data for the new row.

I have gotten this working for when your working on ONE row at the time, but If I have ongoing calls and minimize a row and ajax call 3 and 4 are not done for the previous row, those calls also gets aborted on the newly expanded row.

Simplified code:

```
var openRows = [];
var abort = false;
var ajax1, ajax2, ajax3, ajax4;

$(document).on("click", '.details-control', function (e) {
     var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');

    if ($.inArray(id, openRows) > -1) {
        openRows.splice(openRows.indexOf(id), 1);
        abort = true;
    }
    else {
        openRows.push(id);
        abort = false;
    }

    if (abort) {
        console.log("aborting AJAX");
        if (ajax1 && ajax1.readyState != 4) {
            ajax1.abort();
        }
        if (ajax2 && ajax2 .readyState != 4) {
            ajax2.abort();
        }
        etc...
    }
    else {
         ajax1 = $.ajax({
             ...
         });
         ajax2 = $.ajax({
             ...
         });
         etc...
});
```

So it's pretty easy to understand why the ongoing calls gets aborted when I minimize another row but how can I solve this the best way? Do i use an array with the Ajax calls? Or include the ID in the ajax call variable somehow?

Comment: Why don't you load data for only one accordion(the one which you click)  because even though you load data for all 4 accordion, only one accordion is expandable at a time.

Comment: That is the way we are using it today. It is not really accordion tabs, but subtables working the same way. The problem is that you don't know if any data is availible untill you click it and then having to wait 2-3 seconds before finding out that its no data there slows down productivity.Now I could show if it is and how many rows of data is avalible and it will load instantly (since its already loaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store ajax calls in an array mapped by row index so that you always abort the right one. However, storing all these references to ajax for all these rows may lead to memory leaks.

Why do you have to abort them?

Comment: Doesn't it increase performance on ongoing calls if calls that are taking long time are beeing aborted?

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe no. It's likely that request has already been sent and the server is already procesing it. Perhaps abort() will close Http connection, but the server will still do its thing. 

Besides, the scenario does not seem important enough to optimize.

Comment: You could also wait for these requests, and put data into these hidden tables in the minimized row. Then if user changes his mind again and once again maximizes it, the data is there.

Comment: Ok, yea, I also noticed alot of the times when the requests are aborted I can still see all the data coming in Fiddler even if though the request is marked as aborted.